# How to remove item from an ArrayList using a filtered RecyclerView and OnClickListener

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview, android-adapter, android-filterable

*Check updates below.*

I am making an app for a stair climbing challenge that tracks the date and number of steps taken (user input, not automatic).  I have an `ArrayList` that stored objects containing the following three variables:

```
String date
Int steps
Instant timeStamp
```

The app has two input buttons, one for integer step input, and one for date selection. There is a simple method created to filter the visible list by the selected date and a couple of visual indicators of your daily progress vs. the daily goal for flights of stairs for the day.

**[App screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mKIFt.png)**

I am using the Instant variable as a timestamp to try to get around the issue of the `OnClickListener` selecting the position of the item from the filtered list instead of the corresponding item in the unfiltered list. I do this by using the position reported from the OnClickListener to fetch the timeStamp variable from the associated item in the filtered ArrayList, then compare that timeStamp to the items in the unfiltered `ArrayList` and fetch the indexOf the matching item.

All filtered ArrayLists show properly in the `RecyclerView` when you select a date.

The problem comes in removing items. If I add items only to one date, then you can remove and add items as you'd expect.

**[App function without date change (gif)](https://gfycat.com/vibrantscratchygrub)**

If I add to one date, then another, while they display properly, the items will be removed from the correct position but in the date you first added items, regardless of whether that is the currently selected date or not.

**[App function with changing date (gif)](https://gfycat.com/shorttermresponsiblecockatiel)**

I feel like I'm missing something relatively simple here and my brain is just too saturated with this project to see it.

**Main Activity:**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private RecyclerView mRecyclerView;
    private ExampleAdapter mAdapter;
    private RecyclerView.LayoutManager mLayoutManager;

    Date temp_curr_date = Calendar.getInstance().getTime();
    SimpleDateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MMM-yyyy");
    String sel_date = df.format(temp_curr_date);
    String curr_date = df.format(temp_curr_date);

    double daily_total;
    int progress = 0;
    double daily_goal = 7.5;

    TextView textView1;
    TextView textView2;
    TextView textViewFlights;
    ProgressBar pb;

    List<ExampleItem> mExampleList;
    List<ExampleItem> filteredList;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

// ----- LOAD SAVED ARRAY LIST -----
        loadData();

// ----- SET VARIABLES -----
        daily_total = totalOutput(mExampleList, sel_date);
        textView1 = findViewById(R.id.total);
        textView1.setText(String.valueOf(daily_total));
        textViewFlights = findViewById(R.id.flights);

        pb = findViewById(R.id.progress_bar);
        pb.setProgress(getProgress(mExampleList, sel_date), true);

// ----- BUILD RECYCLERVIEW -----
        buildRecyclerView();
        filter(sel_date);

// ----- ADD STEPS DIALOGUE -----
        setAddStepButton();

// ----- CALENDAR DIALOGUE -----
        setDateChangeButton();
    }

    public double totalOutput(List<ExampleItem> steps, String date) {
        try{
            int temp_total = 0;
            double flight_total;
            for (int a = 0; a < steps.size(); a++) {
                if (date.equals(steps.get(a).getText1()))
                temp_total += steps.get(a).getText2();
            }
            flight_total = round(temp_total / 16.0, 2);
            return flight_total;
        } catch (Exception e){
            return 0.0;
        }
    }

    public static double round(double value, int places) {
        if (places < 0) throw new IllegalArgumentException();

        BigDecimal bd = new BigDecimal(value);
        bd = bd.setScale(places, RoundingMode.HALF_UP);
        return bd.doubleValue();
    }

    public static int toInt(double value) {
        BigDecimal bd = new BigDecimal(value);
        bd = bd.setScale(0, RoundingMode.HALF_UP);
        return bd.intValue();
    }

    public static Date getDate(int year, int month, int day) {
        Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
        cal.set(Calendar.YEAR, year);
        cal.set(Calendar.MONTH, month);
        cal.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, day);
        cal.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 0);
        cal.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 0);
        cal.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
        cal.set(Calendar.MILLISECOND, 0);
        return cal.getTime();
    }

    private void saveData(){
        SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences("shared preferences", MODE_PRIVATE);
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();
        Gson gson = new Gson();
        String json = gson.toJson(mExampleList);
        editor.putString("task list", json);
        editor.apply();
    }

    private void loadData(){
        SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences("shared preferences", MODE_PRIVATE);
        Gson gson = new Gson();
        String json = sharedPreferences.getString("task list", null);
        Type type = new TypeToken<ArrayList<ExampleItem>>() {}.getType();
        mExampleList = gson.fromJson(json, type);

        if (mExampleList == null){
            mExampleList = new ArrayList<>();
        }
    }

    private int getProgress(List<ExampleItem> steps, String date){
        int daily_progress_int;
        try{
            int temp_progress = 0;
            double flight_total;
            for (int a = 0; a < steps.size(); a++) {
                if (date.compareTo(steps.get(a).getText1()) == 0)
                    temp_progress += steps.get(a).getText2();
            }
            flight_total = round(temp_progress / 16.0, 2);
            daily_progress_int = toInt((flight_total/daily_goal)*100);
            return daily_progress_int;
        } catch (Exception e){
            return 0;
        }
    }

    private void addProgress(double x, int prog){
        int daily_progress_int = toInt((x/daily_goal)*100);

        if (progress <= 100-daily_progress_int){
            progress = progress + prog;
            pb = findViewById(R.id.progress_bar);
            pb.setProgress(daily_progress_int, true);
        } else if (progress + daily_progress_int > 100){
            pb = findViewById(R.id.progress_bar);
            pb.setProgress(100, true);
        }

    }

    private void removeProgress(double x, int prog){
        int daily_progress_int = toInt((x/daily_goal)*100);
        progress = progress - prog;
        if (progress <= 100) {
            pb = findViewById(R.id.progress_bar);
            pb.setProgress(daily_progress_int, true);
        } else {
            pb = findViewById(R.id.progress_bar);
            pb.setProgress(0, true);

        }
    }

    public void addItem(String date, int steps, Instant ts){
        mExampleList.add(new ExampleItem(date, steps, ts));
        filter(sel_date);
    }

    public void removeItem(final int position){
        final AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this);
        View viewInflated = LayoutInflater.from(MainActivity.this).inflate(R.layout.confirm, (ViewGroup) findViewById(android.R.id.content), false);
        builder.setCancelable(true);
        builder.setView(viewInflated);
        builder.setPositiveButton("Yup",
                new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        mExampleList.remove(position);
                        mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged(position);
                        filter(sel_date);

                        daily_total = totalOutput(mExampleList, sel_date);
                        textView1 = findViewById(R.id.total);
                        textView1.setText(String.valueOf(daily_total));

                        removeProgress(daily_total,progress);

                        if (daily_total == 1.0){
                            textViewFlights.setText("flight");
                        } else {
                            textViewFlights.setText("flights");
                        }

                        saveData();
                    }
                });
        builder.setNegativeButton("Nope", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            }
        });

        AlertDialog dialog = builder.create();
        dialog.show();
    }

    public void buildRecyclerView(){
        mRecyclerView = findViewById(R.id.recyclerView);
        mRecyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
        mLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);

        mAdapter = new ExampleAdapter(mExampleList);

        mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);
        mRecyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);

        mAdapter.setOnItemClickListener(new ExampleAdapter.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
        public void onItemClick(int position) {
            Instant test = filteredList.get(position).getTimeStamp();
            for (ExampleItem item : mExampleList){
                if (test.compareTo(item.getTimeStamp()) == 0){
                    removeItem(mExampleList.indexOf(item));
            }
        });
    }

    public void filter(String text){
        filteredList = new ArrayList<>();

        for (ExampleItem item : mExampleList){
            if (item.getText1().toLowerCase().contains(text.toLowerCase())){
                filteredList.add(item);
            }
        }

        mAdapter.filterList(filteredList);
    }

    public void setAddStepButton(){
        FloatingActionButton fab = findViewById(R.id.addSteps);
        fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this);
                View viewInflated = LayoutInflater.from(MainActivity.this).inflate(R.layout.add_steps, (ViewGroup) findViewById(android.R.id.content), false);

                // Step input
                final EditText input = viewInflated.findViewById(R.id.input);
                builder.setView(viewInflated);

                // OK Button
                builder.setPositiveButton(android.R.string.ok, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        if (input.getText().length() != 0) {
                            try {
                                int in = Integer.parseInt(String.valueOf(input.getText()));
                                if (in > 0) {
                                    Instant timeStamp = Instant.now();
                                    addItem(sel_date, in, timeStamp);
                                    dialog.dismiss();
                                } else {
                                    dialog.cancel();
                                }
                            } catch (Exception e) {
                                dialog.cancel();
                            }

                            daily_total = totalOutput(mExampleList, sel_date);
                            textView1 = findViewById(R.id.total);
                            textView1.setText(String.valueOf(daily_total));
                            addProgress(daily_total, progress);
                            mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                            filter(sel_date);

                            if (daily_total == 1.0){
                                textViewFlights.setText("flight");
                            } else {
                                textViewFlights.setText("flights");
                            }

                            saveData();
                        } else{
                            dialog.cancel();
                        }

                    }
                });
                // Cancel Button
                builder.setNegativeButton(android.R.string.cancel, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        dialog.cancel();
                    }
                });
                builder.show();
            }
        });
    }

    public void setDateChangeButton(){
        FloatingActionButton fabcal = findViewById(R.id.calendarButton);
        fabcal.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater)getApplicationContext().getSystemService
                        (Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
                LinearLayout ll= (LinearLayout)inflater.inflate(R.layout.calendar, null, false);
                CalendarView cv = (CalendarView) ll.getChildAt(0);

                long milliseconds = 0;
                try {
                    Date d = df.parse(sel_date);
                    milliseconds = d.getTime();
                } catch (ParseException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

                cv.setDate(milliseconds);
                cv.setOnDateChangeListener(new CalendarView.OnDateChangeListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onSelectedDayChange(
                            @NonNull CalendarView view,
                            int year,
                            int month,
                            int dayOfMonth)
                    {
                        Date temp_sel_date = getDate(year, month, dayOfMonth);
                        sel_date = df.format(temp_sel_date);

                        textView2 = findViewById(R.id.daily_total);

                        if (sel_date.equals(curr_date)){
                            textView2.setText("Today");
                        } else {
                            String dt_day = (String) DateFormat.format("dd",   temp_sel_date);
                            String dt_month  = (String) DateFormat.format("MMM",  temp_sel_date);
                            textView2.setText(dt_month + " " + dt_day);
                        }

                        daily_total = totalOutput(mExampleList, sel_date);

                        textView1 = findViewById(R.id.total);
                        textView1.setText(String.valueOf(daily_total));

                        pb = findViewById(R.id.progress_bar);
                        pb.setProgress(getProgress(mExampleList, sel_date), true);
                        mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                        filter(sel_date);
                    }
                });

                new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this)
                        .setView(ll)
                        .setPositiveButton("Ok", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {
                                        dialog.dismiss();
                                    }
                                }
                        ).show();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

**Adapter Class:**

```
public class ExampleAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<ExampleAdapter.ExampleViewHolder> {
    private static List<ExampleItem> mExampleList;
    private static List<ExampleItem> exampleListFull;
    private OnItemClickListener mListener;

    public interface OnItemClickListener{
        void onItemClick(int position);
    }

    public void setOnItemClickListener(OnItemClickListener listener){
        mListener = listener;
    }

    public static class ExampleViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        public TextView mTextView1;
        public ImageView mDeleteImage;

        public ExampleViewHolder(View itemView, final OnItemClickListener listener) {
            super(itemView);
            mTextView1 = itemView.findViewById(R.id.textView);
            mDeleteImage = itemView.findViewById(R.id.image_delete);



            mDeleteImage.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {

                    if (listener != null){
                        int position = getAdapterPosition();
                        if (position != RecyclerView.NO_POSITION){
                            Instant test = mExampleList.get(position).getTimeStamp();
                            for (ExampleItem item : exampleListFull){
                                int compare = test.compareTo(item.getTimeStamp());
                                if (compare == 0){
                                    int delIndex = exampleListFull.indexOf(item);
                                    position = delIndex;
                                }
                            }
                            listener.onItemClick(position);
                        }

                    }
                }
            });
        }
    }

    public ExampleAdapter(List<ExampleItem> exampleList){
        this.mExampleList = exampleList;
        exampleListFull = new ArrayList<>(exampleList);
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public ExampleViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int i) {
        View v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.example_item, parent, false);
        ExampleViewHolder evh = new ExampleViewHolder(v, mListener);
        return evh;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull ExampleViewHolder holder, int position) {
        ExampleItem currentItem = mExampleList.get(position);

        if (currentItem.getText2() == 1.0){
            holder.mTextView1.setText(currentItem.getText2() + " step");
        } else {
            holder.mTextView1.setText(currentItem.getText2() + " steps");
        }
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return mExampleList.size();
    }

    public void filterList(List<ExampleItem> filteredList){
        mExampleList = filteredList;
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
}
```

If anyone out there has any ideas, I'd love to hear from you!

**UPDATE:** The included code now reflects the changes suggested by users and is fully functional.

Answer (score 0):

You should use

```
mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

Instead of

```
mAdapter.notifyItemRemoved(position);
```

For more details Visit
[this.](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView.Adapter.html)

Comment: Thank you for that, I did as you suggested and there is no change to the behaviour.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out, for those interested.  Comparing the timestamps was working fine, but I put it in the wrong part of the `OnClickListener` cycle. It needed to be placed in the `MainActivity` `buildRecyclerView` method in the `setOnClickListener` override.  I've updated original code to reflect this change.

Thank you anyone that took the time to look at my post.

Answer (score 0):

maybe it could be better to place the onClickListner in Your adpater-class..so You can control every single card if it should be clickable or not...or if You want to place any Ads between the cards

GGK